# i'm using react hook useEffect to fetch an advice api. it changed automatically after every page refresh how can i do it automaticly using a button

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

i'm using react hook useEffect to fetch an advice api. it changed automatically after every page refresh  how can i do it automaticly using a button event [image]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] (you get a badge!), have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) I also recommend Jon Skeet's [Writing the Perfect Question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/). Please post code, error messages, markup, etc. **as text**, not as a *picture* of text. Why: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/157247

Comment: Also, your best bet here is to do your research, [search](/help/searching) for related topics on SO, and give it a go. ***If*** you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [mcve] of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a function that fetches your data such as

```
const fetchData=()=>{
//API call
}
```

and add an event to your button that calls the api and uses setState to update it.

```
<button onClick={()=>{
let data=fetchData();
setQuote(data);
}}> </button>
```